# IDE versus command line compiling?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to c++. I have experience on other programming languages so it was way easier now to start studying c++ after learning the philosophy behind programming in general.

This is a bit pointless "question", but after fighting with libraries and includes (to finally understand how they work and what they are) in various IDE softwares (Code::Block, Eclipse, etc..) I realised it was just so much easier for me to build my own g++ building command (.bat) with attributes than to fight with those software menu-hells.
Also I noticed that I actually learned A LOT better how things work when doing things manually.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: It's good to see how things work by doing them manually for understanding. But you'll never ever have the chance to be the at least a bit productive that way... Imagine bigger projects where everyone fumbles with their own .bat-file for building. It'd be gross!

Comment: I do understand that, and that's my problem. Main purpose I fiddled my own environment for now was to build it on USB. So I have it on me all the time because I have to swap computers quite often these days.

Comment: This question has three possible answers: 1) Yes, at least one other person (me) has experienced this. 2) I don't know what the totality of humankind has experienced. 3) I am god and I can attest that nobody else has experienced this. I doubt that 1 or 2 would be useful, and Jon Skeet isn't around.

Comment: This is a better fit for a chatroom topic than a question.  There's really nothing constructive being asked here.

Comment: Thats what version control systems like git etc. are there for... And almost all IDE's will support something like this...

Answer (score 0):

.bat files are quite limited. Makefiles are much better tool. Especially together with helpers like qmake etc. Yet one needs also a good text editor and a bunch of other tools for more special tasks. Having all these stuff, no IDE is needed. But putting it all altogether, it *is* some kind of a "home-grown IDE". But one better suites for your needs. So choose wisely.